# How to make a control's background transparent when placed on top of a 3D window(VTK)

Tags: c#, winforms, vtk

I have few controls like buttons, sliders placed on top of a vtkRenderWindowControl in my WinForms application created with ActiViz.NET(.net wrapper for VTK). I can't get the controls background transparent using conventional techniques.

Comment: Is your form transparent? your controls will be transparent only if your form is transparent.

Comment: I'll check to see if that helps. Were you able to have a transparent background on a control placed on top of a vtkRenderWindowControl ?